# Make text field as a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onfocus

When we click on a dropdown we dont see cursor, we just see the whole box with value gets selected, can we do same with text field because in text field I see the cursor blinking.

see image if confused. :D
[image]

Comment: Your image doesn't show up. Why not just post the code?

Comment: so you just want to remove the cursor from the textbox?

Comment: @jasakguero how?  I did was <input type="text" value="Some value" readonly="readonly" onFocus="this.blur()"/> but now I cant move to next field using tab key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean you want to disable the text input field? (Thats what I can think).  Try this:

```
<input type="text" disabled="true" />
```

What are you trying to accomplish?

Edit: Read only:

```
<input type="text" value="Some value" readonly="readonly" />
```

I think this is what you are looking for. Read only with no focus.

```
<input type="text" value="Some value" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="readonly" />
```

Edit 3, Solving Tab Index problem:

```
Previous field: <input type="text" tabindex=1/>
Disabled field: <input type="text" value="Some value" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="readonly" />
Next Field:     <input type="text" tabindex=2/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery UI's Autocomplete:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: no no I already did auto complete, I want to make it readonly in such a way that user wont be able to click on the field. (so no blinking cursor)

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use any javascript framework, you can create your own java script code for autocomplete. Please look into the example in this page -->
[AutoComplete text box autocomplete](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0560__GUI-Components/AutocompleteTextboxExample.htm)